# Can I use Transporter to upload Flutter iOS apps to App Store console?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I got into mobile development through Flutter, so all my contact with native platforms and techs comes from that.

So far I've been distributing my Flutter apps as the doc says, opening the build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive package with Xcode and validating/distributing it.

I found fastlane, but before getting into it, is there a way to use Transporter to upload iOS apps to Apple Store console? It does not recognize the .xcarchive file with it, I suspect I have to do something else before but I could not find what

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "distribute iOS apps"? All distribution must happen via the Apple app store, whether in beta via TestFlight, or available for sale or free (upon Apple approval).

Comment: @RandalSchwartz yes, that came up confusing... editing the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Archive app with XCode.
- Go to "Distribute" and choose "Export".
- You will have .ipa exported with provisioning profile, and just add it to Transporter app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I just did since brilliant xCode got stuck consistently while trying to upload the app, I switched to Transporter:

1. Run "flutter build ios --release"
2. Copy the generate /build/ios/iphoneos/YourApp.app file to a newly created folder named "Payload"
3. Compress the folder (right click - compress)
4. rename the compressed file to have a ".ipa" instead of a ".zip"
5. upload it using transporter

Comment: How u add the provisioning profile to the ipa?